# How to populate values in vf page from formula field

Tags: visualforce, formula-field

I have created a formula field in lead object with hyperlink which redirects to a page. I need to send lead last name and email to that page to get pre-filled in that.
Formula field is

`IF(
AND(
 Account__r.Id =null,
ISPICKVAL(LeadSource,"INTERNET")
),
HYPERLINK("/apex/Rforce_AccountSearch_Page?caseId="&Id,IMAGE("/resource/CreateAccountButton", "CreateAccount"),"_self"), NULL)`

Please help me out.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AUfSIAW

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gikLAAQ